# How to deploy publish to mysql database using visual studio entity framework code first migrations

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a visual studio asp.net web application that uses entity framework to connect to the database. I follow this tutorial http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/migrations-and-deployment-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application, and enable code first migrations. It connects to local sql server fine and the development is ok.

When I publish this application, I have to use a mysql database. I can't run code first migrations on this database.

I have two problems:

1. I want to use mssql database in development, and mysql database for production, how do I specify two different configs for that?
2. If I follow this tutorial http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/788357/How-to-set-up-application-using-ASP-NET-Identity-w, to setup mysql, how do I switch back to mssql for my development?

Comment: What do you mean you don't know how to configure stuff?

Comment: @Casey see my edit please.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify two different web.configs. One for dev and one for prod. See [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465326(VS.100).aspx) on how.

Comment: I also need to change the Configuration class in Migrations folder, how do I  set that of for dev and production? https://blogs.oracle.com/MySqlOnWindows/entry/entity_framework_4_3_1

Comment: You can use preprocessor directives to use certain code for certain builds. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ed8yd1ha(v=VS.80).aspx

Comment: Ok thanks, an example tutorial using these techniques would be very helpful though @Casey.

Comment: I'll consider writing a blog sometime about it. It's important for you to make an effort with them first though. I told you what the tools you need are and you should at minimum be able to find examples of them elsewhere